# How to remove brackets when bringing values from sqlite database?

Tags: python, excel, sqlite

I am new to Python. I wanna know how to get rid of brackets when bringing values from sqlite.
This is what I have:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(database=r'ims.db')
cur = con.cursor()
wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
cur.execute("Select color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6, color7 from colors")
row= cur.fetchall()
row_num = 14
for element in row:
    ws[f'C{row_num}'].value = str(element)
    row_num += 1
```

So for now in the excel file, it shows`('black', 'yellow', 'pink', '', '', '', '')` and`('red', 'blue', '', '', '', '', '')` but is there anyway to make it to `black`,`yellow`,`pink`...... So that I could insert them into different columns in excel. Anyone help tqsm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would probably use pandas to help you with this

```
import sqlite3
import pandas 

con = sqlite3.connect(database=r'ims.db')
cur = con.cursor()
wb = load_workbook('example.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
query = "Select color1, color2, color3, color4, color5, color6, color7 from colors"
df = pd.read_sql(query, con)
```

This will put it into a dataframe from which you can do a lot more stuff

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution! Have a nice day :)